# DialogFlow google Home Assistant keeps listening, does not pause

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have created a chat bot which responds to request.This is the flow currently happening:

1. I say "Talk to My Test App"
2. My app starts and says welcome message.
3. I request something and my intent is fulfilled

After this the Google Home does not pause but keeps on listening. 
If I stop it then again I will have to say "Talk to My Test App", which I also don't want.

I want google home to sleep after fulfilment.
and Awake in the same app when I say "Ok Google"

More details:-
In my use case the user will talk to the app frequently, for example after every 30 seconds-2mins. I don't want him to say every time "Hey Google" to wake up and then "Talk to My App" and then the command. I also don't want to say long sentence after waking up the Google Home like "Talk to My App to Do this".So I thought it would be better that my app doesn't stop by ending the conversation, instead it should be paused.So that the user can just wake up Google Home and directly pass the command.

Currently Google Home does not pause after the first command and keeps on listening surrounding sounds and responds to the noise, because of this issue user has to stop it.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you please update your question to clarify: (1) If the user stops it, you don't want it to actually stop? (2) What is it doing now, and is this what you want it to do or don't want it to do? (3) Can you provide some examples of how you expect it to behave?

Comment: I have added more details in my question.Please see that.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to have a pause so I can narrate my thoughts but not exit my conversation for a client demo, so I added this in DialogFlow's text response, with a very long break at the end of each text response. I can then interrupt the pause with "Okay Google" and stay within my conversion.

```
<speak>This is a sentence with a <break time="600s"/> pause</speak>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, a conversational VUI suggests that you're going to have a conversation with the agent. Not something with long pauses in between. The assumption is that if there is no reply, that the user isn't actively engaging in the conversation. There is no direct feature that does what you want, although there are a couple of interesting workarounds that might work for you.

First, as you suggest, deep linking with a phrase such as "Hey Google, ask My App to Do This" is certainly a possible approach, and one that you should support. In production, and as a user uses it more, the introduction and hand-off from Google gets shorter and shorter. Even the launch phrase can be shortened with the user creating a Shortcut - but this is a choice of the user, not you.

Although there is no way to "pause" a conversation, there is a way to have the reply include streaming audio that the user can interrupt. Using a [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) begins playing that media.

- When the URL pointed to by the media ends, your Action gets a callback (via an Event in Dialogflow or an Intent with actions.json) indicating the media has ended, and you can do something like play another Media Response, and continue to do this as long as appropriate.
- Are any time, your user can interrupt the audio by saying "Hey Google" and some command. This will trigger any matching Intent, as if they said a command as usual.

There are some caveats with this scheme - some commands don't actually work (anything with "next" in it, for example, since that sounds more like a media command that isn't implemented), and you need an audio of reasonable length that won't be distracting in your environment, but this might be a reasonable solution to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the conversation you may do the following:

1. Go to the dialogflow console.
2. Create and intent (say goodbye).
3. In the Event section, enter '*actions_intent_CANCEL*' in the add event field.
4. Enter your Training Phrases. (Say exit, stop, pause etc)
5. Enter your greetings (say goodbye) in text response. You may skip this if you don't want to reply.
6. Enable '*Set this intent as end of conversation*'.
7. Save